# Add typeguard for null | undefined when "defined" type of value is unknown

Tags: typescript

I have `NotEmpty` validation function that throws an error if value is null / undefined:

```
function validateNotEmpty(data: unknown) {
  if (data) {
    return true;
  }

  throw new Error("Data is empty");
}
```

It is used to validate various types of data, hence I am using `unknown`. I am trying to figure out how to add type guard to this in order for value to come out as "defined" and keep its original type?

For example

```
type TestType = null | undefined | string;
const testValue: TestType = "Hello World";

validateNotEmpty(testValue);

console.log(testValue); // This should be now typed as string only
```

EDIT `validateNotEmpty` is a global utility function used to validate various data types, so it can't know what type it will be if it is not `undefined | null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use assertions or type guards:

```js
function validateNotEmpty<T>(data: T): data is NonNullable<T> {
  return false; // some check here.
}

if (validateNotEmpty(testValue)) {
  console.log(testValue); // works
}
```

or

```js
function validateNotEmpty<T>(data: T): asserts data is NonNullable<T> {
  throw new Error("Data is empty"); // throws in false case.
}

validateNotEmpty(testValue);
console.log(testValue); // works
```

Comment: What if I don't know in advance that data can be `TestType`, i.e this is utility function used across the application validating various data types to check if they are not null or undefined

Comment: You can use generics